# Does the ETF ticker price include its expense ratio?

Tags: etf, commission

When I look at an ETF ticker price, does the price already include the management expense ratio? Or will I get hit by the ratio when I try to sell?

a.k.a if ETF X has a 100$ price with expense ratio= 1%, if I sell it, do I get 100$, or 99$?

Answer (score 2):

You do not pay out the expense ratio at buy or sell (this is where sales loads come out), but instead it is paid out little by little every day, typically, reducing the NAV.